# An object in a TObjectList is not freed when a TObjectList.Clear is called

Tags: delphi

See the code below. I was removed a lot of code for the sake of simplicity, however the remaining code is still quite long, sorry :(

```
  IObserver = interface
    ['{1DD212F8-BD5E-47BF-9A3B-39EF7B9D99B5}']
    procedure Update(Observable: IObservable);
  end;

  TObserver = class abstract (TSingletonImplementation, IObserver)
    strict protected
      //...
    public
      constructor Create;
      destructor Destroy; virtual;
      //IObserver
      procedure Update(Observable: IObservable); virtual; abstract;
      //... 
  end;

  TShapeModification = class abstract (TObserver)
    strict protected
      //...
    public
      //Doesn't have a constructor
  end;

  TRangePointModification = class(TShapeModification)
    strict private
      //...
    public
      constructor Create(...);
      //...
  end;

  constructor TRangePointModification.Create(...);
  begin
    inherited Create;
    //...
  end;
```

Then at some point:

```
TClientClass = class
  strict private
    fList: TObjectList<TShapeModification>;
  public
    constructor Create();
    destructor Destroy(); override;
    procedure Add(ShapeModification: TShapeModification);
end;

constructor TClientClass.Create;
begin
  Self.fList:=TObjectList<TShapeModification>.Create(true);
end;

destructor TClientClass.Destroy;
begin
  Self.fList.Clear;
  FreeAndNil(Self.fList);
end;
```

Finally, at some point:

```
var
  MyClient: TClientClass;
begin
  MyClient:=TClientClass.Create();
  MyClient.Add(TRangePointModification.Create());
  MyClient.Free;
end;
```

When the `MyClient` is freed, the `TClientClass` destructor is called then the internal `fList` is supposed to be cleared but the destructor of `TRangePointModification` (from `TObserver`) is not called. **WHY not?**

(I am using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo)

Comment: Also if a method is virtual in the base class, it will be virtual in all the derived subclasses (in C++ for example it's also true) so you don't need to repeat the virtual keyword. The Destructor is virtual in TObject so, since every class inherits from TObject, every destructor will be virtual! Always remember to override

Comment: @Alberto: if it is declared virtual in a descendant class, a *new* virtual slot is filled and the original method is hidden. But in Delphi (unlike C++), you must use `override` to override it. Omitting `override` also hides the original and will give you a warning. And that is true for destructors too! So you **must** use `override` on `Destroy`!

Comment: Yeah in fact I said "Always remember to override"!! I was pointing out that if a method is virtual then the classed below in the "chain" are virtual too

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look into the warnings - compiler tells you what is wrong:

```
W1010 Method 'Destroy' hides virtual method of base type ...
```

Always put `override` on your destructors (not virtual!)- otherwise the call to `Free` will not execute the code you put into them.

So as a basic advice:

1. always write code that produces zero warnings or hints - they most likely point to a defect that you will encounter sooner or later
2. put a breakpoint into code you suspect to be defect - even when ignoring the compiler warning you would have seen the call to `Clear` was never even made

Comment: Oops!! A fatal mistake! I couldn't see that warning among the ton of compiler hints. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Delmo You shouldn't have "tons of compiler hints".

Comment: @Graymatter I agree with you. I already fixed it. Most of them were just unused variables so I just removed them. Thanks!